# how can i back from one fragment to another fragment in android?

Tags: android, fragment

I am used to developed my applications fragments I have one problem

I am replacing fragments like

A -->B --> C --> D -->E -->F

How can i return back like

A <--B <-- C <-- D <--E <--F

I am using code like

getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();

this worked fine but some times closed app without cross

is there any solution i dnot how to slove the problem due have any idea please guide me

Advance thanks all``

Comment: dont use replace use add in fragment manager and use getchildmanager in nestde fragment..

Comment: what do you mean by `but some times closed app without cross`

Answer (score 3):

With no code available I just post what it's working for me:

when switching from a Fragment to another i use this (if you aren't using the support libraries you have to remove the 'Support' prefix):

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,
            MyFragment.newInstance());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

The addToBackStack adds the fragment to the backstack... so when you press back button the previous fragment will pop up.

Hope it helps.